# A couple of CUDA-performance questions

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, cuda

This is the first time i ask question here so thanks very much in advance and please forgive my ignorance. And also I've just started to CUDA programming.

Basically, i have a bunch of points, and i want to calculate all the pair-wise distances. Currently my kernel function just holds on one point, and iteratively read in all other points (from global memory), and conduct the calculation. Here's some of my confusions:

- I'm using a Tesla M2050 with 448 cores. But my current parallel version (kernel<<<128,16,16>>>) achieves a much higher parallelism (about 600x faster than kernel<<<1,1,1>>>). Is it possibly due to the multithreading thing or pipeline issue, or they actually indicate the same thing?
- I want to further improve the performance. So i figure to use shared memory to hold some input points for each multiprocessing block. But the new code is just as fast. What's the possible cause? Could it be related to the fact that i set too many threads?
- Or, is it because i have a if-statement in the code? The thing is, i only consider and count the short distances, so i have a statement like (if dist < 200). How much should i worry about this one?

A million thanks!
Bin

Comment: Unlike previous generations, Fermi has an automatic cache. So many of the simple tricks you learned in GPU 101, are rendered obsolete.

Comment: One little trick to eliminate branching is to do things like: count += (distance < 200);

Comment: @Nathan: The GPU supports a system called predication. It allows the GPU to "predicate" the execution of a machine code instruction based on some condition. The compiler uses this to avoid branching in conditionals that contain only a few instructions in the body.

Comment: @misha Thanks! Are you suggesting that it is understandable that Fermi's automatic cache might have covered the potential benefits of introducing shared memory?

Comment: @Nathan thanks a lot! The tricky part is I need to use an array to keep track of a bunch of counters, and also there are just a small proportion of distances with dist<200. Currently I'm using global memory (tried the atomic shared memory, but due to possibly too much conflicts, the performance actually got worse), and the thing you propose probably would increase too much memory access. But i guess it should become beneficial if the calculation of every distance has to hit the memory. (sorry for the lengthy explanation)

Comment: @RogerDahl Thanks for the comment! But still if the branch prediction fails, it needs to go back to re-execute the actual instructions, and thus greatly increase the processing time. Is it correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mark Harris has a very good presentation about optimizing CUDA: [Optimizing Parallel Reduction in CUDA](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1.1-Beta/x86_website/projects/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf).

> Algorithmic optimizations
>   Changes to addressing, algorithm cascading
>   11.84x speedup, combined!
>   Code optimizations
>   Loop unrolling
>   2.54x speedup, combined

Having an extra operations statement, does indeed cause problems although it will be the last thing you want to optimize, if not simply because you need to know the layout of your code before implementing the size assumptions!

The problem you are working on sounds like the famous n-body problem,
see [Fast N-Body Simulation with CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch31.html).

An additional performance increase can be achieved if you can avoid doing a pairwise computation, for example, the elements are too far to have an effect on each-other. This applies to any relationship that can be expressed geometrically, whether it be pairwise costs or a physics simulation with springs. My favorite method is to divide the grid into boxes and, with each element putting itself into a box via division, then only evaluate pairwise relations between between neighboring boxes. This can be called O(n*m).

Answer (score 3):

(1) The GPU runs many more threads in parallel than there are cores. This is because each core is pipelined. Operations take around 20 cycles on compute capability 2.0 (Fermi) architectures. So for each clock cycle, the core starts work on a new operation, returns the finished result of one operation, and move all the other (around 18) operations one more step towards completion. So, to saturate the GPU, you might need something like 448 * 20 threads.

(2) It's probably because your values are getting cached in the L1 and L2 caches.

(3) It depends on how much work you're doing inside the `if` conditional. The GPU must run all 32 threads in a warp through all the code inside the `if` even if the condition is true for only a single of those threads. If there is a lot of code in the conditional as compared to the rest of your kernel, and relatively view threads go through that code path, it is likely that you end up with low compute throughput.

Comment: Thanks again roger! 1 & 3. Very clear. But could you please elaborate between the relationship between pipeline you mentioned and warp? As i understand each warp, let's say containing 32 threads, execute the same instructions "altogether". Are they actually forming a pipneline?

Comment: 2. So i guess the caches here is the same as Misha indicated above, that "Fermi has an automatic cache. So many of the simple tricks you learned in GPU 101, are rendered obsolete."?

Comment: @bin: When processing starts on an instruction in a warp, the instruction (with different operands) is issued to 32 cores. Then the whole warp is put on hold while the operation travels through the pipelines in the 32 cores. Some types of instructions need the load/store and special function units. There aren't 32 of each of those units, so for those, the warp is scheduled multiple times, until all its threads are serviced.

Comment: @RogerDahl The scheduler will pick a warp and issue 1 or 2 instructions (2 only support on CC 2.1 and above). The pipeline will read the registers and any constants and dispatch the instruction to a data path (execution unit). If the execution unit is not wide enough for 32 threads then it will be issued over multiple cycles. The number of cycles it takes before the instruction retires is different for each instruction type and each architecture. If the warp is not stalled (e.g. data or execution dependency) then the schedule can issue another instruction on the same warp in the next cycle.

Comment: @RogerDahl The number of threads that can be allocated on a SM is based upon the occupancy and device limits. The maximum ranges from 768 on CC < 1.1 to 2048 on CC 3.x. The number of instructions that can be inflight if you include math pipes, LSU, and TEX is several hundred. The data pipes are pipelined and instructions to different data pipes can complete out of order. The number of threads necessary to saturate a SM (let alone a GPU) is dependent on the instruction mix, instruction level parallelism, and data dependencies. 50% occupancy is a good estimate.